# Expected value of multiple of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have to random variables. X with the values -1, 0, 1 each with the probability 1/3, and Y with the value 0, 1 with the probability 1/3 and 2/3 respectively. As part of the questions have to find E(XY) and no can't use E(XY) = E(X)*E(Y). So I guess my question is how to get the expected value of multiplying 2 random variables.

EDIT: X and Y aren't independent as Y is X^2

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why can't you use the product of expectations? Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If not, how do they depend on each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $Y=X^2$, then $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X^3] = \sum_{x\in\{-1,0,1\}} x^3 \Pr[X=x]$.

Comment: (face palm) so simple